# Redirecting to a specific page depending on which link you click

Tags: php, redirect

I have a weird problem with my code.

I'll explain.

I have 2 pages. I want to go from one page to another page. I have to show information that belongs to the link, deepending on which link I click. Now I use:

```
<a href=profile.php?comment_username={$comments['username']}>{$comments['username']}</a>
```

So I am using this in 3 different situations. 2 are working but the other one isn't:

1. The working one:

Page 1:

```
$sql_result = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM questions");

    while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {


    echo <<<EOT
    <table>
    <th><a href=thread.php?thread_id={$thread['thread_id']}> {$thread['title']} </a></th>
    </table>
    EOT;

    $_SESSION['idcheck']=$thread['thread_id'];
    }
```

Page 2:

```
$thread_id =$mysqli2->real_escape_string($_SESSION['idcheck']);
$sql_result = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE thread_id = '".$thread_id."'");
```

So now I can show the result on the page.

1. The 2nd working one:

page 1:

```
while ($plant = $resultaat->fetch_assoc()){
echo <<<EOT
<form method="get" action="sql.php">
<a href="plant.php?plantcode={$plant['plantcode']}"> {$plant['plantnaam']} </a> 
//some more stuff
</form>
EOT;
}
```

page 2:

```
$plantcode = $_GET['plantcode'];
$resultaat = $mysqli->query("select plantcode, plantnaam, kleur, soort, prijs, hoogte, bloeitijd_start, bloeitijd_einde from plant where plantcode={$plantcode}");
```

Again after all this I can show the information that belongs to the link they click.

Now my problem.

I don't think I can use either of them. In the 1st example I am using `SESSIONS`, which I can't do in my 3rd one because it's a question/comment page and you can click on the usernames but usernames of the comments are in a different sql table. I actually tried `SESSIONS` but when I click on comments usernames, it will direct to the username that belongs to the question.

At my 2nd page I am using a form so I can use `GET`. I **could** use that but I actually dont want to use a form. So these are my problems.

Sorry for making it so vague.
What I actually want to know is, I know how to redirect with 1 variable and then show the information that belongs to it, but my question/comments page has 2 different variable but should still go to the same page when clicked and show the information that belongs to the username. So I use: `SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$profileusername."'` > Which I cant with 2 variables

This is my situation:

Page 1:

```
<a href=profile.php?thread_username={$thread['username']}> {$thread['username']}</a>

<a href=profile.php?comment_username={$comments['username']}>{$comments['username']}</a>
```

Page 2:

Depending which link they click, the value should come here:

```
$profileusername =$mysqli2->real_escape_string();
$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$profileusername."'");
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your problem is, however, I think that it boils down to a misunderstanding about `GET`... If using a hyper-link `<a></a>` with get variables (i.e. `?key=value`) you **do not** have to put it in a form.

Comment: @Steven My problem is, I should redirect to a 2nd page, depending on which username I clicked. So normally you would do like: GET[$username] but I have comments and questions. So I actually have 2 variables. How can i redirect to a page liek that?

Comment: So you want to send two variables to the page? You can still use `GET`, like this: n your `href` attribute put `http://www.mysite.com/page.php?key1=value1&key2=value2` so `key1` would be _for example_ `username` and key two would be `plantcode` with their respective values

Comment: @Steven No I want to send 1 with it, depending what link you click. If you click the questions username, he should send $thread['username'] If he clicks ONE OF the comments he should send: $comments['username']

Comment: Maybe I am just thinking to difficult but I cant seem to think of a solution.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a different variable name? E.g. _For threads_ `?tusername=USER_NAME` and _for comments_ `?cusername=USER_NAME` then you could check which one is present from php and go from there... Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @Steven I do think I understand what you mean and you're probably right  but how do I check which one is present?

Comment: `if(!empty($_GET['tusername']){/*code for thread username*/}elseif(!empty($_GET['cusername'])){/*code for comments username*/}else{/*No username present*/}`

Comment: Probably not the easiest thing to read in a comment :P

Comment: @Steven Could you give it in an answer? and I don't really get what you mean with /*code for thread username*/ and /*code for comments username*/  What would that be in my case?

Comment: Okay, done, hopefully that makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link would either be:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/?thread_username=THREAD_USERNAME"   >Thread Username </a>
<a href="http://mysite.com/?ccomment_username=COMMENT_USERNAME">Comment Username</a>
```

To check which it is:

```
if(!empty($_GET['thread_username'])){
    //If thread username link was clicked
    $profileusername = $_GET['thread_username'];
}
else if(!empty($_GET['comment_username'])){
    //If comment username was clicked
    $profileusername = $_GET['comment_username'];
}
else{
    //No username has been entered
}

//Continue with rest of your code:
$profileusername =$mysqli2->real_escape_string();
$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$profileusername."'");
```

Comment: You do know the last 2 lines are in a different page? Shouldn't I use a session? Or should this all be in the 2nd page?

Comment: I assumed that when you click on the link it takes you to that page?

Comment: I got it thanks man. All of this should be on my second page. It worked. Really appreciate it man. +1 and accepted answer